# Second View shifts upward when flipped from First View

Tags: ios4, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am building an ap in which I need to remove the present view from the superView and load another one. But **the new loaded view shifts upward**. Also when the firstView is again loaded, it loads perfectly.

Could anyone possible suggest something to get rid of this issue.

Following is the method I am using to flip the view to secondView

```
-(void) flipToBack
{
CreateMessageViewController *oSecondView = [[CreateMessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateMessageViewController" bundle:nil];
[self setMsgViewController:oSecondView];
[oSecondView release];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:window cache:YES];

[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:[msgViewController view]];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Looking forward to your kind responses.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time playing around with the code and IB, I found the bug. It was corrected as

Open the mainWindow.xib and add the UIViewController Object from the Library. Change its class to your Class that handles the specified viewController and then comes the click. Go to the properties section of the Attribute Inspector and set the respective Nib Name for the Controller and now save and exit the IB.

And the code changes to

```
-(void) flipToBack
 {
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:window cache:YES];

     [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
     [tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
     [self.window addSubview:[msgViewController view]];
     [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Thanks to all who responded!!

Answer (score 0):

There is not much I can tell without looking at the big picture. Check the frames in the IB to see if they are correctly set. 
Is this code from your appDelegate? Does viewController have a toolbar shown on his view? Maybe your view is shifted the exact pixels your toolbar height is?

Comment: thanks for the reply...... but the frames in IB are perfectly placed and the shift is not equal to the height of toolbar. The problem persisted even when there was not any toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
It's happening due to the IB settings. So in IB your viewController has a statusBar and your view has a height of 460 (for iPhone) not 480. The 20 points are the statusBar height. When transitioning to the second view, its rect is `{0,0,320,460}` so the view is positioned behind the application's statusBar and you are missing 20 points from the bottom.

To get around this you need to:

1. Go into IB and set the CreateMessageViewController's statusBar to Unspecified.
2. Go into the view size section and set the view's height to 480 (for iPhone).

Now your CreateMessageViewController's view will show properly.

Comment: thanks for the reply ... but even that did not help..... the view gets into position if i load another view over it and then remove it using presentModalViewController method........ Kindly suggest ne other way to tackle it.... thanks